# Catch Exit code 3

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple never-ending winforms background app that saves pictures from web cam on hard drive, does some work with them, and then deletes them. Picture saving and processing are two independant processes with the first one being a bit faster. To not overload disk with pics, I have set a limit to picture count that can be saved at the moment. For that I use Queue of strings.

Problem is that sometimes app crashes with exit code 3 (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`). Which seems kind of impossible to be happening from my code as there is only one path I am using and at no point it is being tempered with. I have also set everything possible in try catch blocks, but nothing is caught. I think that it could be coming from one of two bigger libraries that I use. Is there a way to catch where this nasty thing is happening?

Ok, so here is the code that saves the images:

```
void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) 
{
    videoSource.NewFrame -= videoSource_NewFrame;
    if (snapshotsQueue.Count < 100) 
    {
        Image myImage = (Image)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        string strGrabFileName;
        if (firstFrame) 
        {
            firstFrame = false;
            // extension is png
            strGrabFileName = String.Format(
                "{0}\\{1}.{2}", snapshotsPath, "0.0", 
                snapshotExtension.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()); 
            snapshotTimer.Start();
        }
        else 
        {
            strGrabFileName = String.Format(
                "{0}\\{1}.{2}", snapshotsPath,
                snapshotTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), snapshotExtension.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        }

        try 
        {
            myImage.Save(strGrabFileName, snapshotExtension);
            snapshotsQueue.Enqueue(strGrabFileName);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            writeError(e.Message);
            writeToLog(e.Message);
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    if (videoSource != null) 
    {
        videoSource.NewFrame += videoSource_NewFrame;
    }
}
```

And file reading:

```
while (true) 
{
    try 
    {
        if (videoSource == null && snapshotsQueue.Count == 0) return;
        while (snapshotsQueue.Count == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
        var snapshot = snapshotsQueue.Dequeue();

        // process image
        File.Delete(snapshot);    
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        writeError(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add checks to see if the [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.100).aspx) or [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2756s2b(v=vs.110).aspx) exists at all, before you continue with your code. Maybe that catches something?

Comment: To solve you should provide some code which shows your affords and where you´ll get the exception.

Comment: @MarleenSchilt Done that already. And for the record - from what I'v red, the problem shouldn't be occuring from missing file, because then it would be a different error as exit code 3 is specifically for directory

Comment: wow, such downvote. Not that I care, but what's the problem?

Comment: Well, you may just provide the relevant code where the exception is thrown, not your whole application - at least I guess so.

Comment: @HimBromBeere There is no exception, that's the thing!

Answer (score 1):

You may catch `ThreadException`s and all `UnhandledException`s:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(HandleThreadException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(HandleUnhandledException);

    //... do your stuff
}

static void HandleThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   //log the exception or something else
}

static void HandleUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   //log the exception or something else
}
```

This should catch all exceptions that haven't been catched somewhere else!
The `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` catches exceptions from your main UI thread, while the `ThreadExceptionEventHandler` gets notified on uncaught exceptions in non-UI threads.

For further reading see the MSDN on [`UnhandledException Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ThreadException Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx). You may even have to set the [`UnhandledExceptionMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'll try this, thanks. Hopefully, I won't have to wait forever for it to happen.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this didn't catch anything neither... To make sure, I put it both, in program main method and form main method. App still simply stops working from time to time without throwing any exception at all...

Answer (score 0):

I really dont recommend this as a long term answer - but you can do an overall application catch and even restart your app.

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
Application.OnThreadException += MyHandler;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += otherHandler;
```

you can put this in the program.cs of your app

Id suggest you look at converting it to a service rather than a constantly running app.. I also cant help but feel there are error traps which you could do more gracefully somewhere in the app.

In your handlers, you can of course if its that semi terminal

```
Application.Restart();
```

Which does exactly as it sounds.